Bounded Quotient of Lipschitz functions should be continuou.
Take $f,g \in C([0,1]) $ Lipschitz, ${{f}\over{g}} \in C((0,1))$ and $\exists \infty >C>0 \forall x \in (0,1) |{{f(x)}\over{g(x)}}| < C $.
I want to prove that ${f \over g} \in C([0,1])$ is well defined and continuous on the closed intervall.
I am not a 100% sure if this is true.
There are classical counter examples if either f or g is not Lipschitz. However I feel like the statement above should be true, since Lipschitz + boundedness should provide enough regularity.

Just as a possibility: consider $f$, $g$ given by $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$, $g(x) = x^2$, with $f(0) = 0$; then both are Lipschitz (to see this for $f$, use the mean-value bound), their quotient is well-defined everywhere in $(0, 1]$, and is bounded (by $\leq 1$). However, their quotient $\sin(1/x)$ certainly cannot be extended to a continuous function on the entire interval $[0, 1]$. (The issue is that having boundedness does not automatically suppress oscillations, which are a major obstruction to continuity on the whole space.)

You're right. Do you think you can ask striker conditions to make it convergent?

A requirement of uniform continuity of the quotient $f / g$ on $(0, 1)$ is the main one I'm thinking about right now; the issue seems to be that even strong forms of boundedness are not enough (for instance, even if you mandate a two-sided condition $M > |f / g| > m > 0$ on the interval, the same counterexample works, just using $2 m x^2 (1 + \sin(1/x))$, say). In general, taking $g$ to be a nonvanishing Lipschitz function, $f = b g$ for a bounded but otherwise-pathological function $b$, this gives a family of counterexamples for many conditions that would be natural to hypothesize.

You would get continuity if there was some form of nonvanishing, either $|f|$ or $|g|$ being lower-bounded by a strictly-positive quantity on the entire interval. But the issue is that these are conditions on $f$ or $g$ individually, and can't be enforced very well through placing conditions on their quotient; again, the $f = b g$ example means that $f/g$ can be decently horrible even when $f$, $g$ are nice.

I see. Thank you very much. This was very helpful!
